# Automapper, Map a list of parent elements into a child list

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I'm struggling using AutoMapper to map these objects.
Here are my DTO:

```
public class ContainerDTO
    {
        public List<MoneyAccountDTO> MoneyAccounts { get; set; }

        public List<CardDTO> Cards { get; set; }
    }

public class MoneyAccountDTO
    {
        public string Iban { get; set; }
    }

public class CardDTO
    {
        public string MoneyAccountIban { get; set; }
    }
```

Here are the BusinessObject:

```
public class Container
    {
        public List<MoneyAccount> MoneyAccounts { get; set; }
    }

public class MoneyAccount
    {
        public string Iban { get; set; }

        public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    }

public class Card
    {
        public string MoneyAccountIban { get; set; }
    }
```

What i try to achieve here, is to find all CardDTO in the ContainerDTO that have the same Iban than a MoneyAccount and Create a list of these cards in the MoneyAccount itself.

The probleme here is that i receive the CardsDTO object at the same level as the MoneyAccountDTO it related to.

I started with something like that:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ContainerDTO, Container>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.MoneyAccounts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cards.
                                                                             Where(c => c.MoneyAccountIban == XXX)));
```

But i'm unable to replace those XXX by the Money account the mapper is enumerating. It think i'm not in the right direction.

I'm unable to find a good solution for this mapping.
Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is to use a foreach with a where clause.

```
cfg.CreateMap<ContainerDTO, Container>().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.MoneyAccounts
                                                              .ForEach(a => a.Cards = src.Cards
                                                                       .Where(c => c.MoneyAccountIban == a.Iban)
                                                                                         .Select(d => Mapper.Map<CardDTO, ICard>(d)).ToList()));
```

It works like a charm !